# How to stop LaTex numbering equations within section

Tags: equations, numbering

```
\documentclass[]{phstyle}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb, undertilde}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{makeidx}

%Preamble

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

%\include{chapI}   these 2 lines are because the chapters are different tex files

%\include{chap1}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

%\setcounter{chapter}{0}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Chap I Section1}

\begin{equation}
this is equation I.1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
this is equation I.2
\end{equation}

\section{Chap I Section2}

\begin{equation}
this is equation I.3
\end{equation}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Chap 1 Section 1}

\begin{equation}
this is equation 1.1.1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
this is equation 1.1.2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

I have been typing Chapters 1-5 that contain sections and subsections and equations. The equations were numbered globally, i.e. if I had 3 equations in section 1 of Chap 1, they were numbered 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3 and for Section 2, the equations were 1.2.4, 1.2.5, etc. 
Recently I had to change Chap 1 and everything in it to Chapter I (roman number) and Chap 2 were renumbered to Chap 1, etc.

My problem is that LaTeX started numbering the equations in Chap I (the other chapters did not have this problem) according to the sections and not globally anymore. That is, the 3 equations in Chap I were I.1, I.2, I.3, and the equations in the second section of Chap I became I.1, I.2, etc instead of I.4, I.5, etc

I needed the prefix to be the chapter and not the sections.
I don't understand why there is a change. I have never used `\numberwithin` in my book

Here are some of my codes

```
\documentclass[]{phstyle}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb, undertilde}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

for the equation numbering in Chap I

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}} **
```

Previously when Chap I was Chap 1, ** was

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
```

I have also tried the line below but it didn't work

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{I.\arabic{equation}}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Instead of operating directly on `\theequation`, you could issue the command `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}` in the preamble of your document, after the `amsmath` package has been loaded. (The `amsmath` package provides the command `\numberwithin`.)

Comment: Also, perhaps [this](http://www.hpjava.org/papers/NOWbook/phstyle.cls) is your document class.

Comment: Your MWE works fine if I substitute `phstyle` with `report`. There must be a problem with the document class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you're describing seems to be caused by the fact that the [phstyle class](http://www.hpjava.org/papers/NOWbook/phstyle.cls) includes the instructions

```
\def\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
```

To override this behavior and have  the equations numbered by chapter instead, insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{section} % undo numbering system provided by phstyle.cls
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}  % implement desired numbering system
```

Comment: What a lifesaver! Thanks Mico! I clicked the check sign before I read about the vote up and vote down buttons. Now when I try to vote up, it tells me it needs 15 reputations before it can get upvoted. My upvote didn't get registered. Sorry Mico.

Comment: sorry to once not comply with the comment standards, but you Sir, are awesome.

Comment: @ItsmeJulian - You're most welcome! :-)